# Why is putStrLn not atomic?

Tags: haskell, concurrency

To practice concurrent programming, I wrote the following (suboptimal) program, which repeatedly calculates the first prime bigger than whatever the user inputs:

```
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Concurrent.Chan
import Control.Monad (forever)
primeAtLeast n = -- Some pure code that looks up the first prime at least as big as n

outputPrimeAtLeast n = putStrLn $ show $ (n, primeAtLeast n)

main = do
    chan <- newChan
    worker <- forkIO $ forever $ readChan chan >>= outputPrimeAtLeast
    forever $ (readLn :: (IO Int)) >>= (writeChan chan)
    killThread worker
```

I want to have a worker thread in the background that does the actual calculation and outputs `(n, primeAtLeast n)` as soon as it's finished.

What it's doing now: As soon as I enter a number `n`, it immediately outputs `(n,`, returns the control to the main thread, calculates `primeAtLeast n` in the background and outputs the second half `primeAtLeast n)` as soon as it's finished.

So is `putStrLn` not atomic? Or where is the problem?

Comment: tbh I kindof like this behaviour of `show` and `putStrLn` ;)

Comment: btw: do you want to know how to fix it (see @chi s answer) or do you want to know why (lazy IO / evaluation - strings are char lists)?

Comment: @CarstenKönig, so output works char by char? Agree, that's pretty neat.

Comment: `putStrLn` can work for infinite `String`s, or for `String`s that raise exceptions after you've output an initial part of them, e.g. `show (1, undefined)`. It couldn't do this if it were atomic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
outputPrimeAtLeast n = let p = primeAtLeast n in p `seq` putStrLn $ show (n, p)
```

The above forces the computation of the prime before the `putStrLn` is run.

Further, you may use `print` instead of `putStrLn . show`:

```
outputPrimeAtLeast n = let p = primeAtLeast n in p `seq` print (n, p)
```

Alternatively, you may use a `putStrLn` function which forces every single character before starting printing anything.

```
strictPutStrLn :: Show a => a -> IO ()
strictPutStrLn x = let str = show x in str `listSeq` putStrLn str

listSeq :: [a] -> b -> b
listSeq []     w = w
listSeq (x:xs) w = x `seq` listSeq xs w
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why doesn't a `where` instead of a `let` work? I get an `Out of Scope` error if I do that.

Comment: @Turion `where` should work as well... are you indenting it at least one space on the right than `outputPrimeAtLeast`?

Comment: It seems it's got something to do with using it in monads:
main = do
 n <- readLn :: IO Int
 print x where
  x = n*2
That gives the same error.

Comment: @Turion You can't use `where` to refer to variables bound inside a `do` (or `let`, or `case`, ...). `where` only sees the function parameters.

Comment: @chi Actually that's not true for `case`, but then you must put the `where` on the match you want to use the variables of.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Ah, interesting! I had never seen that before. Apparently `case ... of { pattern -> expression where bindings }` is valid syntax. Good to know, thanks.